# Which is the most lightweight torrent client?

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, ubuntu-minimal

Which is the most lightweight torrent client which works on Lubuntu-Core (Lubuntu Minimal Install)?

I would be interested to be as slim as possible, with as few options as possible...

Thank you.

Comment: @Maythux, tell me please is the topic still a duplicate if the most important think in this case is the using of hardware resources? not "Speed to start downloading (Search Speed, Seed, Leech)
Speed while downloading" like in the duplicate indicated post? If is a duplicate I will press on "That solved my problem" if no, should I edit my question ? Thanks.

Comment: Of course @Maythux, I will do that. Tell me please in here it still could be a duplicate? Thanks.

Comment: I told you just visit the link and check the list, there you can find most GUI torrent files so of course you still can find a light one, it just need to read answers there, and yes it's a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I really like `Transmission` as a bittorrent client.  It is lightweight, easy to use and not a lot of settings in it.

[Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-modern-linux-torrent-clients-for-fast-downloads/) is a list of torrent client apps that could be helpful to you.